# How to add link my react card component to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a card component as a react component and I'm trying to link it to another page. Should I link it inside the `card.js` component or inside my `index.js`?

When users click on each card it should link to another page.

```
        <div className="CardGroup">
            <Card
            title="JCDECAUX Festive Card"
            text="Illustration"
            image={require('../images/christmas-card-1.jpg')} />
            <Card 
            title="Go Wild"
            text="Motion Design"
            image={require('../images/Go-wild-thumbnail.png')} />
            <Card 
            title="Phase"
            text="UI design"
            image={require('../images/Phase-hackthon-image.png')} />
            <Card 
            title="Shine"
            text="UI design"
            image={require('../images/shine-app.jpg')} />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should handle it in card.js so please use it with props.

Comment: const Card = props => (
    <div className="Card">
        <img src={props.image} />
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        <p>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
)

How Do i link it to another page from here?

Comment: Can you explain why it should be handled in `card.js`?